# apache rewrite rule with multiple parameters

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm new to the .htaccess things, I'm trying to make something like that.

```
localhost/easyApy/?tablename=%tablename% => localhost/easyApi/%tablename%
localhost/easyApy/?tablename=%tablename%&action=get&id=%id% => localhost/easyApi/%tablename%/get/%id%
localhost/easyApy/?tablename=%tablename%&action=delete&id=%id% => localhost/easyApi/%tablename%/delete/%id%
localhost/easyApy/?tablename=%tablename%&action=update&id=%id% => localhost/easyApi/%tablename%/update/%id%
localhost/easyApy/?tablename=%tablename%&action=add => localhost/easyApi/%tablename%/add
```

Thanks! :)

Comment: So you are trying to make a table. Or a list of strings. Or something. You did. Do you have any question here?

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely looking for something like that:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?easyApi/(\w+)/get/(\d+)/?$    /easyApi/index.php/?tablename=$1&action=get&id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?easyApi/(\w+)/delete/(\d+)/?$ /easyApi/index.php/?tablename=$1&action=delete&id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?easyApi/(\w+)/update/(\d+)/?$ /easyApi/index.php/?tablename=$1&action=update&id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?easyApi/(\w+)/add/?$          /easyApi/index.php/?tablename=$1&action=add [L]
RewriteRule ^/?easyApi/(\w+)/?$              /easyApi/index.php/?tablename=$1 [L]
```

Note: this assumes that your `id`'s are of numeric type.

That rule set will work likewise in dynamic configuration files or in your http servers host configuration.

Keep in mind that exposing your database in such a transparent manner is a major security issue. And no, the fact that this is just meant to be used "locally" is *not* a good reply to that. Not at all.

---

And a general hint: you should always prefer to place such rules inside the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow down the server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have control over the host configuration (read: really cheap hosting service providers) or if you have an application that relies on writing its own rewrite rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: `easyApy` should be the path `localhost/easyApi` my bad :)

Comment: I doubt that `localhost/easyApi` is actually meant to be a _path_. Reads more like something that _might_ be interpreted as a URL missing the protocol scheme and pointing to the local system.

Comment: Syntax errors in the main config file can cause the whole server to stop. (.htaccess simply won't be read for requests on other pathes.) So please put only waterproof and thoroughly tested rewrites inside your production server config.

Comment: full path is: `localhost/easyApi/index.php?tablename=%tablename%`

Comment: @itzikb Once more, `localhost/easyApi/index.php?tablename=%tablename%` is _not_ a path. It is a string that _might_ be interpreted as the URL `http://localhost/easyApi/index.php?tablename=mytable`. The _path_ in that would be `/easyApi/index.php`. But that is only a guess. Please be precise in your naming to prevent miss understandings.

Comment: @itzikb I modified the rule set according to what you probably mean in your comments here.

Comment: whats `^/?easyApi/` this mean? get parameter or htaccess syntax?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "htaccess syntax"... You might refer to the syntax of a `RewriteRule` though... `^/?easyApi/` is the _matching pattern_ in such a rule. I suggest you start reading the documentation of the tool you are trying to use. That actually should be the first thing to do when starting out: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule